# Pass Django list as argument to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a list passed through the context into the html page of a Django project which I want to read inside of a .js which contains chartjs code. The problem is that .js is reading as string and not as a list/array.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        "data": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Then, in the html page I have to pass the `{{ data|safe }}` to a javascript like so:

```
<script src='{% static "js/chart.js/linechart.js" %}'
   var label = "fakelabel";
   var index = {{ data|safe }};
></script>
```

Inside the .js I'm reading the 'index' input as:

```
document.currentScript.getAttribute("index")
```

How can I fix this? ('label' is read correctly as str indeed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to fix the above problem is:

**`views.py`**

```
def index(request):
   context ={"data": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
   return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**`charts.html`**

Then, in the html script you should add `{{ data|json_script:"index" }}` like you you do with the 'static' tag. Then, always in your .html script you do not need to pass the 'index' list. Therefore when you call the javascript inside your .html you just need to pass:

```
{{ data|json_script:"index" }}
<script src='{% static "js/chart.js/linechart.js" %}'
   var label = "fakelabel";
></script>
```

**`js/chart.js/linechart.js`**

Finally, inside you separate javascript (in this case *"js/chart.js/linechart.js"*), we can fetch the list with:

```
JSON.parse(document.getElementById('index').textContent)
```

Answer (score 1):

{{ data|safe }} is not a safe way to output a Python object as JavaScript.

Use json_script if you want to be safe

This is how to do it.

Write your object as json:

```
data = {'numbers':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']}

def index(request):
    context = {"data": data}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

```
<script>
   var index = {{ data|json_script:'mydata' }};
<script>
```

Then you can use the index variable into another scrip like this:

```
  <script>
    const data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('mydata').textContent);
    mydata = data['numbers'];
  </script>
```

You could (and probably should) point to an external JavaScript file rather than using embedded JavaScript.
read [here](https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/) for more details

Comment: Can you please explain your process using my example? Why did you change the context form. What did you write inside the .html code where the script has to pass the arrays into the .js code. What did you write in the separate javascript code to fetch the data passed from the .html?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to fetch list or dict data from views and you need to add jQuery cdn in html file.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def indexAjax(request):
   context={"data":[1,2,3,4,5]}
   return JsonResponse(context,safe=False)
```

Inside your js file or script tag

```
function fun(){
   $.ajax({
      url:"{% url'indexAjax" %},
      dataType:'json',
      type:'GET',
      success:function(res){
           console.log(res.data)
           //here you can write your chartjs
           }
    })}
```